# Casting to string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

I found three ways to cast a variable to `String` in JavaScript.
I searched for those three options in the jQuery source code, and **they are all in use**.
I would like to know if there are any differences between them:

```
value.toString()
String(value)
value + ""
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/67NaT/)**

They all produce the same output, but does one of them better than the others?
I would say the `+ ""` has an advantage that it saves some characters, but that's not that big advantage, anything else?

Comment: Seems to me that if all things are equal, the standard `toString()` would be the way to go.

Comment: @asawyer. And why is that? If they all produce the same output and do the same, pick one and go with it. This is my opinion _if this is really the case here_.

Comment: First two methods should be equivalent (you should check the standard but constructor will call toString). The 3rd one USUALLY produces the same output but it involves a very different mechanism (besides speed it involves different calls so it may not be what you expect for every kind of object).

Comment: In my opinion `toString` is semantically the clearest way to self document the fact that you are trying to get a string equivalent of an object. `String(...)` is a little obtuse, and `value + ""` is a bit of a hack.  It also gives you the ability to override the default `toString` with a custom implementation if you ever needed to I suppose, as a minor side benefit.

Comment: I agree with @asawyer, the "+" involves valueOf/toString and I can't imagine why someone would do it. I'm pretty sure noone will use "new String()" because of the null check at least in 99% of cases.

Comment: @Adriano. But `+ ""` is the fastest according to the jsperf, so... it does it ni some other way I guess.

Comment: @gdoron with toString() there is an extra check for null before the method call. According to 11.6.1 the "+" operator should call ToString() for both operands if one of them is a string. Results are pretty different for each browser (different optimizations paths?)

Comment: `+ ""` doesn't work reliably.. e.g. `"" + 308e65` yields `"3.08e+65"`

Comment: Some behaviours are browser-specific.  I suggest a prior test before casting otherwise things could go horribly wrong.  For similar reasons, `.toString()` is best, but you must either have an exception handler or first check that `toString` can actually be called on the value you have (which may be `null` or `undefined`).  Unless you're in a repetitive loop, speed is not a concern.

Answer (score 277, accepted):

They do behave differently when the `value` is `null`.

- `null.toString()` throws an error - *Cannot call method 'toString' of null*
- `String(null)` returns - *"null"*
- `null + ""` also returns - *"null"*

Very similar behaviour happens if `value` is `undefined` (see [jbabey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11083457/369247)).

Other than that, there is a negligible performance difference, which, unless you're using them in huge loops, isn't worth worrying about.

Comment: This is actually an interesting difference. So you should refrain from using `toString()` when you haven't checked for `null` yet.

Comment: @SammyS. don't know if printing `null` or `undefined` to the screen is a more desirable behaviour then a javascript error...

Comment: @JustusRomijn: True indeed. In the meantime, I started to use the Option type to handle such errors.

Comment: you can check any of these casted variables with typeof to check for string. typeof (null+'') == 'string'

Comment: There is another case when they behave differently. `v + ''` returns incorrect result if v has both toString() and valueOf() methods. Concatenation will ignore toString() and will use valueOf(). Example of a class for which concatenation fails: https://github.com/processing-js/processing-js/blob/67a092cca45ec16ee66217dfd5a5e67b035c05f4/src/Objects/Char.js

Comment: @JustusRomijn I would be wary of the first one - `null.toString()` or `undefined.toString()` one. As that could lead to a broken page (subsequent scripts may error). When compared to a broken page, printing the 'null' or 'undefined' text may be a lesser issue.

Comment: As an alternative to `myVar + ""`, there is also `myVar + []` (which is used extensively by [JSFuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSFuck)).

Answer (score 36):

There are differences, but they are probably not relevant to your question. For example, the toString prototype does not exist on undefined variables, but you can cast undefined to a string using the other two methods:

```
​var foo;

​var myString1 = String(foo); // "undefined" as a string

var myString2 = foo + ''; // "undefined" as a string

var myString3 = foo.toString(); // throws an exception
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f8YwA/

Comment: If a variable is not at all defined, you will still get an error for `String()`. Example: `String(test);` throws `Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined`, while `var test; String(test);` will result in `"undefined"`.

Answer (score 21):

They behave the same but `toString` also provides a way to convert a number binary, octal, or hexadecimal strings:

**Example:**

```
var a = (50274).toString(16)  // "c462"
var b = (76).toString(8)      // "114"
var c = (7623).toString(36)   // "5vr"
var d = (100).toString(2)     // "1100100"
```

Answer (score 14):

In addition to all the above, one should note that, for a defined value `v`:

- `String(v)` calls `v.toString()`
- `'' + v` calls `v.valueOf()` prior to any other type cast

So we could do something like:

```
var mixin = {
  valueOf:  function () { return false },
  toString: function () { return 'true' }
};
mixin === false;  // false
mixin == false;    // true
'' + mixin;       // "false"
String(mixin)     // "true"
```

*Tested in FF 34.0 and Node 0.10*

Answer (score 10):

According to [this JSPerf test](http://jsperf.com/cast-to-string/2), they differ in speed. But unless you're going to use them in huge amounts, any of them should perform fine.

For completeness: As [asawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/426894/asawyer) already mentioned, you can also use the `.toString()` method.

Comment: That jsperf has the same test twice, [I edited it](http://jsperf.com/cast-to-string/3) And the `new String()` returns an object not a `String`

Comment: `new String()` returns an object yes. `String()`, however, returns a string, which is the one in the question.

Comment: This is not entirely true. As you can see from the results, concatenating an empty string and an object does **not** yield the same result as concatenating an object and an empty string. Furthermore, `new String(blarg)` gives you a `String` object you can call `toString()` on. In my Chrome debugger, they effectively result the same kind of object except said difference.

Comment: @SammyS. Could you please add example performance results to your answer? The jsperf link currently is down and certainly will be again in the next 5+ years.

Answer (score 9):

if you are ok with null, undefined, NaN, 0, and false all casting to '' then `(s ? s+'' : '')` is faster.

see http://jsperf.com/cast-to-string/8

note - there are significant differences across browsers at this time.

Comment: "[T]here are significant differences across browsers at this time" should be good enough reason to disregard this.  Nothing's changed much in 10 years, apart from the limitation of browser choice.

Answer (score 6):

Real world example: I've got a log function that can be called with an arbitrary number of parameters: `log("foo is {} and bar is {}", param1, param2)`. If a `DEBUG` flag is set to `true`, the brackets get replaced by the given parameters and the string is passed to `console.log(msg)`. Parameters can and will be Strings, Numbers and whatever may be returned by JSON / AJAX calls, maybe even `null`.

- `arguments[i].toString()` is not an option, because of possible `null` values (see Connell Watkins answer)
- JSLint will complain about `arguments[i] + ""`. This may or may not influence a decision on what to use. Some folks strictly adhere to JSLint.
- In some browsers, concatenating empty strings is a little faster than using string function or string constructor (see JSPerf test in Sammys S. answer). **In Opera 12 and Firefox 19, concatenating empty strings is rediculously faster (95% in Firefox 19)** - or at least [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/cast-to-string/2) says so.

Comment: +1 for a real world example.  Here's another gotcha with jQuery: `$('#field-id').val()` returns `undefined` if there is no such field.  Casting this to a string (by whichever method) before testing it results in a failure: either an exception that's unhandled, or the string "UNDEFINED" which is indistinguishable from the user input "UNDEFINED".  Of course, it would be better and much more expected if JS converts it to an empty string, but it's browser-specific.  Make sure you know what you're dealing with when using any of the above.  Don't break your site for the sake of a few microseconds.

Answer (score 0):

On this page you can test the performance of each method yourself :)

http://jsperf.com/cast-to-string/2

here, on all machines and browsers, ' **"" + str** ' is the fastest one, (String)str is the slowest

Comment: Function over form, please, or, in this case, reliability over performance.  `"" + str` results in the string "UNDEFINED" when `str` is undefined, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Backticks**

so:

```
`${varibale}`
```