# Map null values to array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why isn't `null` added to my `keys` array below?

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" data-codekey="1"/>
<input type="radio" data-codekey="null"/>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){

  var keys = $step.find('input[type="radio"]').map(function (i, el) {

        return $(el).data('codekey');

  }).get();

console.log(keys); // [1]
//desired result: [1, null]

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mewem/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the `.map()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

> If the function returns null or undefined, no element will be inserted.

The `.data()` function does type conversion and (apparently) assumes the string `"null"` should be converted to the value `null`. It also converts the string`"1"` to the number `1`.

Use `.attr()` instead of `.data()` and you'll get the actual string `"null"`:

```
return $(el).attr('data-codekey');
```

If you want an actual `null` you can't use `.map()`, you'd have to rewrite it with an `.each()` loop or something:

```
var keys = [];
$step.find('input[type="radio"]').each(function () {
    keys.push( $(this).data('codekey') );
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I'll just push them manually to a result array using `each()`. Thanks

Comment: For people googling ES6 Array.map , it does not function the same as this answer. Returning falsey will add to the array.

Comment: @LessQuesar -  Yes, this is about jQuery's $.map() - which does keep other falsey values, just not null or undefined. Since writing this answer (which was years ago) I've found that with the jQuery function returning `[null]`, (that is, returning an array with null as an element) will put `null` into the new array. Or use .call() or .apply() to use the native .map() with the jQuery object.

Answer (score 4):

Over a year later, it appears that either things have changed with map() or the original answer missed something in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/).

> The function can return:
>
> - the translated value, which will be mapped to the resulting array
> - null or undefined, to remove the item
> - an array of values, which will be flattened into the full array

The solution here is in the last bullet: simply return an array containing a single element, even if it's null.  The arrays will be flattened into the results, and the nulls will not be removed:

```
$([ null, null, null, 1, null]).map(function (i, el) {
    return [ el ];
}).get();
```

Gets this result:

```
[ null, null, null, 1, null ]
```

Comment: When you refer to the docs, you should refer to the correct map method: http://api.jquery.com/map/

Comment: Great solution. I use like this to avoid the "null" string: `function(el) { if (!el) {el = ""} return el }`

Answer (score 1):

Null values are not inserted into that

[**SEE HERE**](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

Answer (score 1):

> If the function returns null or undefined, no element will be inserted.

[**Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

You can cast to string like:

```
$(el).data('codekey') + "";
```

Read this: [Casting to string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11083254/601179)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply move the `.get()` call before `.map()`. This will have you using the more predictable [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function, which allows `null`:

```
var keys = $step.find('input[type="radio"]').get().map(function (el) {
    return $(el).data('codekey');
});
```