# JavaScript casting number to string test with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm writing some unit tests for my JS code using the Jasmine framework to learn the basics of Jasmine.  This is more of a JS question than it is a Jasmine question.

I checked out the JS string conversion methods and looked at [Casting to string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083254/casting-to-string-in-javascript).  I may be using toString() incorrectly.

The function I wrote looks like:

```
function factorial(input) {

    var result = 1;

    if(input === 0) {
        result = 0;
    } else if(input < 0) {
        result = "cannot compute factorial of negative number";
    } else if(input.isString) {
        result.toString();
        result = "input is not a number";
    } else {
        for(var i = 1; i <= input; i++) {
            result *= i;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The Jasmine spec looks like:

```
describe("Factorializer", function() {
    it("factorial() should return the correct factorial value of an input > 
        0.", function() {
            expect.factorial(3)).toBe(6);
    });

    it("factorial() should return 0 if the input = 0.", function() {
        expect.factorial(0)).toBe(0);
    });

    it("factorial() should return 1 if the input = 1.", function() {
        expect.factorial(1)).toBe(1);
    });

    it("factorial() should return an error if the input is negative.",
        function() {
            expect.factorial(-5)).toBe("cannot computer factorial 
                negative number");
    });

    it("factorial() should return an error if the input is not a 
        number.", function() {
            expect.factorial("Herro")).toBe("input is not a number");
    });

    it("factorial() should return an error if the input is not a 
        number.", function() {
            expect.factorial("Herro")).toBeNaN();
    });
});
```

Whenever the input is a string, result is always 1.  Either the else if(input.isString) is never entered, or the result is not being assigned the value it's supposed to in the statement.  I am leaning towards the former, because the previous else if seems to be working (it passes the Jasmine test).  The last two Jasmine tests are failing, which is good since it confirms that Jasmine is working and I caught a problem with my code.

I'm trying the fix the problem that Jasmine found; I'm not trying to alter the Jasmine tests unless their is something wrong with them, which I don't think there is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `input.isString` with `typeof input === 'string'`, and get rid of `result.toString();`. It's not doing anything useful.

Edit: Also, your last two tests appear to be redundant.

Comment: Yes, they are redundant, but I was just checking if I was using Jasmine correctly.  Thanks, your fix works.  Why doesn't isString work?  And after the fix, the last Jasmine test failed.

Comment: There is no `isString` property built into JavaScript. The common way to check type is to use `typeof`, though it can be unreliable in certain situations. For example, if a string is created with `var x = new String()`, then `typeof x` will return `'object'`. But really, who uses `new String()`, right :)

Comment: For more about `typeof`, check out [this reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof). You may also want to check out [this reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) about `instanceof`.

Answer (score 0):

```
} else if(input.isString) {
    result.toString();
    result = "input is not a number";
```

The above isn't doing anything.

There is no `isString` property in javascript, and `.toString()` is a function that returns a value, it does not edit in place, and it wouldn't matter anyway because you're overwriting it on the following line anyway!

Personally, I'd go with something more like

```
input = parseInt(number, 10);
if (isNaN(input)) {
    result = 'input is not a number';
}
```

Comment: Be aware that something like `parseInt('12abc', 10)` will return 12. This may not be desirable.

Comment: I didn't know that there wasn't an isString property in JS.  IntelliJ just autocompleted it for me.