# Filter array of objects whose any properties contains a value

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I'm wondering what is the cleanest way, better way to filter an array of objects depending on a string keyword. The search has to be made in any properties of the object.

When I type `lea` I want to go trough all the objects and all their properties to return the objects that contain `lea`

When I type `italy` I want to go trough all the objects and all their properties to return the objects that contain `italy`.

I know there are lot of solutions but so far I just saw some for which you need to specify the property you want to match.

ES6 and lodash are welcome!

```js
  const arrayOfObject = [{
      name: 'Paul',
      country: 'Canada',
    }, {
      name: 'Lea',
      country: 'Italy',
    }, {
      name: 'John',
      country: 'Italy',
    }, ];

    filterByValue(arrayOfObject, 'lea')   // => [{name: 'Lea',country: 'Italy'}]
    filterByValue(arrayOfObject, 'ita')   // => [{name: 'Lea',country: 'Italy'}, {name: 'John',country: 'Italy'}]
```

Comment: Favor on-site stack snippets over off-site services like jsfiddle.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You could filter it and search just for one occurence of the search string.

Methods used:

- [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), just for filtering an array with conditions,
- [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) for getting all property names of the object,
- [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for iterating the keys and exit loop if found,
- [`String#toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) for getting comparable values,
- [`String#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) for checking two string, if one contains the other.

```js
function filterByValue(array, string) {
    return array.filter(o =>
        Object.keys(o).some(k => o[k].toLowerCase().includes(string.toLowerCase())));
}

const arrayOfObject = [{ name: 'Paul', country: 'Canada', }, { name: 'Lea', country: 'Italy', }, { name: 'John', country: 'Italy' }];

console.log(filterByValue(arrayOfObject, 'lea')); // [{name: 'Lea', country: 'Italy'}]
console.log(filterByValue(arrayOfObject, 'ita')); // [{name: 'Lea', country: 'Italy'}, {name: 'John', country: 'Italy'}]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: If one of the property is not a string but a object we might want to use this `function filterByValue(array, string) {
    return array.filter(o => {
     return Object.keys(o).some(k => {
       if(typeof o[k] === 'string') return o[k].toLowerCase().includes(string.toLowerCase());
      }); 
    });
}`

Comment: you could shorten it  without an `if` statement with `return typeof o[k] === 'string' && o[k].toLowerCase().includes(string.toLowerCase());`

Comment: If the values are not always strings, then use `String(o[k])` instead of just `o[k]`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11083415/2110294

Comment: Also, it would be good to check the type of argument 'string' in the begging, like this function filterByValue(array, string) {
  return   typeof string === 'string'   && array.filter(o =>
        Object.keys(o).some(k => {
return typeof o[k] === 'string' && o[k].toLowerCase().includes(string.toLowerCase())));
}

Comment: function filterByValue(array, string) {
    return array.filter(o =>
        Object.keys(o).some(k => o[k].toString().toLowerCase().includes(string.toString().toLowerCase())));
}   
Slight changes

Comment: would be nice if the function could loop through the child objects as well

Comment: @JonHarding, which child?

Comment: @NinaScholz when it checks the o[k] it seems to just move on if it's an object. would be nice to have it check that object

Comment: @JonHarding, why not implement this yourself?

Comment: @NinaScholz so you just wanted to ask which child to patronize?

Comment: @JonHarding, it is not my request, what do you want?

Answer (score 22):

Well when we already know that its not going to be a search on an object with methods, we can do the following for saving bit on time complexity :

```
function filterByValue(array, value) {
  return array.filter((data) =>  JSON.stringify(data).toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
}
```

Comment: This will find the search keyword on the keys of the object too, but may OP just want to search on the values only.

Comment: yeah, that can be avoided using regex. The idea here was to eliminate the loop over keys of an object

Comment: how to just loop over keys?

Comment: @chris_r Once you know that its an hashmap kind of object i.e. no methods, you can always write a regex to do what you want to do. This holds good even for nested objects.

Comment: Example would help.

Comment: @chris_r a specific question would help.

Comment: This was helpful. I also was hoping to find an example here. For anyone else hoping for a nice example here is what I wrote and works for my case.
`JSON.stringify(terminal).replace(/("\w+":)/g, '').toLowerCase()`.

This turns 
`"{"myKey":"myValue","myKey2":"myValue2","mySubObject":{"subKey":"subValue"}}"` 
into 
`{"myValue","myValue2","subValue"}`

Comment: This is the best.

Answer (score 9):

Use Object.keys to loop through the properties of the object. Use reduce and filter to make the code more efficient:

```
 const results = arrayOfObject.filter((obj)=>{
     return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, curr)=>{
           return acc || obj[curr].toLowerCase().includes(term);
     }, false);
});
```

Where term is your search term.

Comment: Great! What about highlight search criteria? Can you help me add same tag replacing searched criteria. Something like '<strong>' + term + '</strong>'

Comment: @Vincent Ramdhanie Is it possible replace searched term without loop through all objects array?

Answer (score 5):

You can always use `array.filter()` and then loop through each object and if any of the values match the value you are looking for, return that object.

```js
const arrayOfObject = [{
      name: 'Paul',
      country: 'Canada',
    }, {
      name: 'Lea',
      country: 'Italy',
    }, {
      name: 'John',
      country: 'Italy',
    }, ];
    
let lea = arrayOfObject.filter(function(obj){
  //loop through each object
  for(key in obj){
    //check if object value contains value you are looking for
    if(obj[key].includes('Lea')){
      //add this object to the filtered array
      return obj;
      }
     }
    });
      
console.log(lea);
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use `Array#filter`, `String#toLowerCase` and `String#indexOf` like below.

```js
const arrayOfObject = [{
            name: 'Paul',
            country: 'Canada',
        }, {
            name: 'Lea',
            country: 'Italy',
        }, {
            name: 'John',
            country: 'Italy',
        }];

        function filterByValue(arrayOfObject, term) {
            var ans = arrayOfObject.filter(function(v,i) {
                if(v.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) >=0 || v.country.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) >=0) {
                    return true;
                } else false;
            });
            console.log( ans);
        }
        filterByValue(arrayOfObject, 'ita');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version of the above which filters by a value which is derived from an array of object's property. The function takes in the array of objects and the specified array of object's property key.

```js
// fake ads list with id and img properties
const ads = [{
  adImg: 'https://test.com/test.png',
  adId: '1'
}, {
  adImg: 'https://test.com/test.png',
  adId: '2'
}, {
  adImg: 'https://test.com/test.png',
  adId: '3'
}, {
  adImg: 'https://test.com/test-2.png',
  adId: '4'
}, {
  adImg: 'https://test.com/test-2.png',
  adId: '5'
}, {
  adImg: 'https://test.com/test-3.png',
  adId: '6'
}, {
  adImg: 'https://test.com/test.png',
  adId: '7'
}, {
  adImg: 'https://test.com/test-6.png',
  adId: '1'
}];

// function takes arr of objects and object property
// convert arr of objects to arr of filter prop values
const filterUniqueItemsByProp = (arrOfObjects, objPropFilter) => {
  return arrOfObjects.filter((item, i, arr) => {
    return arr.map(prop => prop[objPropFilter]).indexOf(item[objPropFilter]) === i;
  });
};

const filteredUniqueItemsByProp = filterUniqueItemsByProp(ads, 'adImg');

console.log(filteredUniqueItemsByProp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function filterByValue(arrayOfObject,words){
  let reg = new RegExp(words,'i');
  return arrayOfObject.filter((item)=>{
     let flag = false;
     for(prop in item){
       if(reg.test(prop)){
          flag = true;
       }  
     }
     return flag;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it using lodash:

```
const filterByValue = (coll, value) =>
  _.filter(coll, _.flow(
    _.values,
    _.partialRight(_.some, _.method('match', new RegExp(value, 'i')))
  ));

filterByValue(arrayOfObject, 'lea');
filterByValue(arrayOfObject, 'ita');
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested using a `for` loop solution.

- Outer loop: Iterate the array.
- Inner loop: Iterate the object keys of the `array[index]`
- Inner loop: Check if `typeof array[index][key] === 'string'` and the `array[index][key]` contains the search key -> store the `array[index]` to the `filtered` array.

```
function filterByValue(array, string) {
   let filtered = Array();

   for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
      const keys = Object.keys(array[i]);

      for(let j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) { 
         const value = array[i][keys[j]];

         if(typeof value === 'string' &&
            value.toLowerCase().includes(string.toLowerCase())) { 

            filtered.push(array[i]);
            break;
         } else {
            continue;
         }   
      }   
   }
   
   return filtered;
}
```

```
const arrayOfObject = [
   {
      name: 'Paul',
      country: 'Canada',
   }, {
      name: 'Lea',
      country: 'Italy',
   }, {
      name: 'John',
      country: 'Italy',
   }, 
];

console.log(filterByValue(arrayOfObject, 'lea')); 
// [{name: 'Lea', country: 'Italy'}]

console.log(filterByValue(arrayOfObject, 'ita')); 
// [{name: 'Lea', country: 'Italy'}, {name: 'John', country: 'Italy'}]
```