# How to create onkey up search in array using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to create keyup search in Array which contains Names using JavaScript. My arrray is like,

```
[
 {
  "first_name": "abc",
  "account_id": 1
 },
 {
  "first_name": "Test",
  "account_id": 2
 },
 {
  "first_name": "Hasad",
  "account_id": 3
 }
]
```

When user add text to text box like,

> User input: a
>
> Output: abc, Hasad

This should be work like search using sql query in database. Please help me with this.

Comment: So you just want your array that you already have, to be filtered?

Comment: You need to have tried something for us to help you.

Comment: Exactly I want that array to be filtered @LazarNikolic

Comment: do you like to look in only one property, or in all, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44312924/1447675

Comment: I'm trying to filter with every index of the input box @MattEllen

Comment: Only one property first_name @NinaScholz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple filter function

```js
const data = [
 {
  "first_name": "abc",
  "account_id": 1
 },
 {
  "first_name": "Test",
  "account_id": 2
 },
 {
  "first_name": "Hasad",
  "account_id": 3
 }
];

function search(input){
  const filtered = data.filter(element => {
     for (const value of Object.values(element)) {
       if (value.toString().toLowerCase().includes(input.value.toLowerCase())) return true;
     }
  })
  document.getElementById("result").innerText=JSON.stringify(filtered)
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="search(this)">
<div id="result">[{"first_name":"abc","account_id":1},{"first_name":"Test","account_id":2},{"first_name":"Hasad","account_id":3}]</div>
```

please take a note of the fact that my function searched all fields of the objects, for the required value and returns list of objects meeting the criteria for you to use in any way required.

Also if the amount of data you are searching is significantly larger you may consider using `debounce` function to trigger it only ever so often (ex. after user stops typing for a second)

Comment: what do you mean by "add test"

Comment: put test in search box

Comment: my search is case sensitive, if you put "Test" it is working

Comment: @KunalDholiya I've added `.toLowerCase()` to the function above to make it case insensitive

Answer (score 1):

You could `.filter()` your arary to only include results where `first_name` includes the search letter, and then `.map()` your array:

```js
const arr = [
 {
  "first_name": "abc",
  "account_id": 1
 },
 {
  "first_name": "Test",
  "account_id": 2
 },
 {
  "first_name": "Hasad",
  "account_id": 3
 }
];

const search = 'a';
const res = arr.filter(({first_name}) => first_name.includes(search)).map(({first_name}) => first_name);

console.log(res);
```

However, this approach isn't very efficient as you need to loop each object, and then every `first_name` for each search. If you're looking for something efficient, you could use a [prefix-trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) to help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

You could filter an map by taking a lower case strings.

```js
var data = [{ first_name: "abc", account_id: 1 }, { first_name: "Test", account_id: 2 }, { first_name: "Hasad", account_id: 3 }],
    key = 'first_name',
    value = 'a',
    result = data
      .filter(o => o[key].toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()))
      .map(o => o[key]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function searchFunction() {
  const arrayValue = [{
      "first_name": "abc",
      "account_id": 1
    },
    {
      "first_name": "Test",
      "account_id": 2
    },
    {
      "first_name": "Hasad",
      "account_id": 3
    }
  ];

  const searchValue = document.getElementById('txtsearch').value;
  const response = arrayValue.filter(({
    first_name
  }) => first_name.includes(searchValue)).map(({
    first_name
  }) => first_name);

  console.log(response);
  document.getElementById('showResponse').innerHTML = response
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='txtsearch' name='txtsearch' onkeyup="searchFunction()" />
<div id='showResponse'></div>
```