# Retrieving JSON data with certain values

Tags: json, angular

I am trying to retrieve posts from the JSON data with a certain tag.

```
data: any = 
[
    {"id": 1, 
    "title": "title 1", 
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum.", 
    "by": "author",
    "tags": [
        { "tag":"facebook" }, 
        { "tag": "twitter" } ]
    },
    {"id": 2,
    "title": "title 2",
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum.",
    "by": "author",
    "tags": [
        { "tag": "google" }, 
        { "tag": "twitter" } ]
    },
    {"id": 3,
    "title": "title 3",
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum.",
    "by": "author",
    "tags": [ 
        { "tag": "reddit" }, 
        { "tag": "instagram" } ]
    },
    {"id": 4,
    "title": "title 4",
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum.",
    "by": "author",
    "tags": [
        { "tag":"reddit" },
        { "tag":"9gag" } ]
    }
];
```

The output I want to retrieve are the post using a certain tag.
let's say that the certain tag I want is "9gag", the result should output something like this:

```
result: any = 
    [
        {"id": 3,
        "title": "title 3",
        "description": "Lorem Ipsum.",
        "by": "author",
        "tags": [ 
            { "tag": "reddit" }, 
            { "tag": "instagram" } ]
        },
        {"id": 4,
        "title": "title 4",
        "description": "Lorem Ipsum.",
        "by": "author",
        "tags": [
            { "tag":"reddit" },
            { "tag":"9gag" } ]
        }
    ];
```

Comment: The article with id:3 doesn't match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to do that.

```js
const data = [{ "id": 1, "title": "title 1", "description": "Lorem Ipsum.", "by": "author", "tags": [{ "tag": "facebook" }, { "tag": "twitter" } ] }, { "id": 2, "title": "title 2", "description": "Lorem Ipsum.", "by": "author", "tags": [{ "tag": "google" }, { "tag": "twitter" } ] }, { "id": 3, "title": "title 3", "description": "Lorem Ipsum.", "by": "author", "tags": [{ "tag": "reddit" }, { "tag": "instagram" } ] }, { "id": 4, "title": "title 4", "description": "Lorem Ipsum.", "by": "author", "tags": [{ "tag": "reddit" }, { "tag": "9gag" } ] } ]; 

function getPostsByTag(posts, tag) {
  return posts.filter(post => post.tags.some(item => item.tag === tag));
}

console.log(getPostsByTag(data, "9gag"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of Articles, so you can use the filter:

```
let result = data.filter(...)
```

and then apply the condition:

```
article.tags.some(tag => (tag.tag.includes(yourString)))
```

so finally:

```
let yourString = "9gag";
data.filter(
  article => (article.tags.some(
                tag => (tag.tag.includes(yourString))
             )
  )
);
```

A great example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44313087/7604006