# Filter Array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am making a search bar, to filter a table I have.
I know how to filter an array of objects by a specific value, for example "team" values see code below:

```
const characters = [
  { name: 'Batman', team: 'Justice League' },
  { name: 'Hulk', team: 'Avengers' },
  { name: 'Flash', team: 'Justice League' },
  { name: 'Iron Man', team: 'Avengers' },
  { name: 'Avengers', team: 'X-Force' }
];

const avengers = characters.filter(character => character.team === 'Avengers');
```

My Questions is, what if want to filter it by any of the properties in the object contains the value Avengers? without doing it the manual way like:

```
  const avengers = characters.filter(character => character.team === 'Avengers' || character.name === 'Avengers');
```

The reason why I don't want to do it this way is because some of the objects are quite large...

Comment: `Object.values()` + `Array.prototype.some()`, or a simple `for...in...` / `for...of...` loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter array of objects whose any properties contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312924/filter-array-of-objects-whose-any-properties-contains-a-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
  const avengers = characters.filter(character => !!Object.values(character).find(e => e === 'Avengers'));
```

Comment: maybe better to use .some instead, as it returns a boolean.

Comment: I get the following error when trying to do so: "Uncaught TypeError: Avengers is not a function"