# Filtering data based on array of strings

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a data set of recipes that I am trying to filter based on an array of inputs.

```js
const [cuisineInput, setCuisineInput] = useState("");
const [cuisineFilter, setCusineFilter] = useState<Filter[]>([]);
const [filteredResults, setFilteredResults] = useState<any>(null);

const filterDataByCuisine = useCallback(() => {
  if (cuisineFilter !== null) {
    const filteredData = data!.hits.filter(({ recipe }: any) => {
      return Object.values(recipe.cuisineType)
      .join("")
      .includes(Object.values(
        cuisineFilter.map((el) => {return el.label;}))
        .join("")
        .toLowerCase()
      );
    });
    setFilteredResults(filteredData);
  }
}, [cuisineFilter, data]);
```

Here I am setting the filtered data (filteredData) to a new state (filteredResults). I am then mapping over the new data of filtered data to display in the UI. The Issue I am having is I can not filter by multiple input "lables" in the *cuisineFilter* array. I am mapping over the *cuisineFilter* array to grab the label because it is an object containing {id: number, label: string} that I am also displaying in the UI. *recipe.cuisineType* is an array of
a single string like ["italian"].

If I only have one "label" in the *cuisineFilter* array it works fine and filteres the data as expected, but I want to be able to filter by multiple "labels". How can I make the data filter by multiple inputs in the *cuisineFilter* array?

Comment: Your code snippet is throwing an error

Comment: Right, because I just provided the function with the logic I has struggling with and not the full react component.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter array of objects whose any properties contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312924/filter-array-of-objects-whose-any-properties-contains-a-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I have the data structures right, but does the following help? I think you want to filter to recipes that have a match in their cuisineType array for every label from the filters array.

```js
const recipes = [
  { name: 'Spaghetti bolognese', cuisineType: ['italian', 'pasta', 'tomato'] },
  { name: 'Caramel and pecan gelato', cuisineType: ['italian', 'dessert', 'pecan', 'caramel'] },
  { name: 'Deep fried macaroni cheese pie', cuisineType: ['scottish', 'pasta', 'pie', 'cheese', 'cardiac_failure'] },
  { name: 'Pecan pie', cuisineType: ['american', 'pecan', 'pie'] }
];

const filter_recipes = (recipes, filters) => {
  const filter_terms = filters.map( (filter) => filter.label );
  return recipes.filter(
    (recipe) => filter_terms.every( (term) => recipe.cuisineType.includes(term) )
  );
};

console.log(filter_recipes(recipes, [{ label: 'italian' }]));
console.log(filter_recipes(recipes, [{ label: 'italian' }, { label: 'pasta' }]));
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. The .every() method you used lead me in the right direction!